# Does whois command breaches the security?

Tags: command-line, legal, whois

My question is very simple and I have been wondering that we usually use `whois` command to get some information about website or websites , maybe sometimes those data from that website meant to be sensitive or protect able thing ,

so we cannot get those information without owner's approval in that way **using this command would be a computer crime** ?

Comment: You cannot commit a crime by looking at public information. See also this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WHOIS#Law_and_policy

Comment: yes it's not a crime by looking at public information . I'm asking that `whois` only provides public information?

Comment: When you register a domain, you can pay extra to have your information be private.  One wishes that were the default instead, but there you have it. http://www.networksolutions.com/education/you-need-private-registration/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So just as a little background about me, I am not a lawyer and this shouldn't be taken as legal advice, I work in the cybersecurity industry and have some focus on GDPR.

The whois command was a subject of debate in the run-up to GDPR. It does have some privacy concerns associated with it, which is why the methods of data collection and the data collected using it was changed to limit the information the command would return. It now returns less information that might be considered private by a domain owner.

Comment: Thanks @sam Chapman . I was wondering why this question closed by some down vote . `whois` isn't related to Linux / Unix ???

Comment: It's not Linux/Unix related, it's a tool available on most OSs and there are web accessible variants too